# Searching by title, content and custom taxonomy

Tags: wp-query

Is there any way to search for a string in title, content AND taxonomy using wp_query?

I am using:

```
$args = array(

'post_type' => 'firma',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'order' => 'DESC',
'orderby' => 'date',
's' =>$_POST['term'],
'posts_per_page' =>5

);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But this is searching using

```
AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%string%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%string%')))
```

only in title and content.

Answer (score 1):

`[WP_Query][1]` provides list of options including `[Taxonomy Parameters][2]`. You can use the taxonomy parameter to search the posts like:

```
post_type' => 'firma',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'order' => 'DESC',
'orderby' => 'date',
's' =>$_POST['term'],
'posts_per_page' =>5
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => $_POST['term'],
    )
);
```